# i tried to run a C program using its executable file ,but nothing happened

Tags: c, linux

inspite of using gcc compiler i doubleclicked the binary executable file but nothing seems to happen  .
can anybody tell  me  is it possible and how can i run my program just by doubleclicking the binary executable file.

```
#include  <stdio.h>
#include  <stdlib.h>
#include  <errno.h>
#include  <unistd.h>
#include  <sys/types.h>
#include  <sys/wait.h>
#include  <string.h>
int main(void)
{
    pid_t pid;
    char ch;
    switch(pid = fork()) {
    case -1:
         perror("fork"); /* something went wrong */
         exit(1);         /* parent exits */
    case 0:
     FILE *fpaste,*fcopy;
     fpaste=fopen(xyz,"w");
     fcopy=fopen(abc,"r");
     while(1)  
         {  
            ch = getc(fcopy);  
            if(ch==EOF)  
        {  
            break;  
        }  
        else  
             putc(ch,fpaste);  
     }  
     fclose(fcopy); 
     fclose(fpaste);
     }
     exit(0);
   default:
         printf("PARENT: I'm outta here!\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

i was just playing with fork()  then  suddenly i encountered this doubt .    the code runs fine i checked the output also. plz can any body tell me   why    and  what to do. i also checked with  my  other c programs .. same  thing  ..

Comment: We're going to need a lot more detail to answer this one!

Comment: What does your program do? Do you have the source code? Can you show at least its main function?

Comment: Without seeing your program's code, it is unclear whether it should do anything.  What do you expect to happen?  Should it display a window?  Send output to `stdout` or `cout`?  Play the Ninth Symphony?

Comment: Nothing massively wrong with this question, why the downvoting?

Comment: @Troubadour, I agree that people should try to help, rather than close the question.  People on SO are really becoming jerks.

Comment: The real problem is in there (to wit, it's not running in the graphical shell), but I missed it the first few time. You'll want to edit the question (and possibly the title because "it's executable" does not convey that you were working in the GUI) to emphasize *what you are asking*. And of course try to be more clear in future questions. Nonetheless, voting to reopen.

Answer (score 4):

Well, that depends on what the program does. If it is a console program, then it won't do anything if you just double click it. You need to run it in a terminal. That might be available in the settings or you could simply open a terminal and run it there.

Comment: i was trying the basic fork program which will open a file  , it works fine with terminal , can u now  tell me - what to do if possible to execute by doubleclicking

Comment: @user481831 Check the properties (right click -> properties). Some desktop environments will allow you to configure this.

Answer (score 0):

When you double clicked the file it probably tried to start but failed. Try starting it from a terminal and see what errors you get. It might be unable to locate shared libraries for example.

Comment: there is no error  it works fine     and its not even a system program  , can any body telll me what  to do  for execution by doubleclicking